# Saving changes with an existing dataReader open with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions, datareader

Im trying to read a bunch of music tracks from my database, edit them on the file system, and then save the changes in the database. Im working with about 2m rows and in my experence mass updating in EF is pretty slow. That combined with the fact that if something wrong happens there would be a lot of inaccurate data on the database.

So i have a query i use and then i get an Enumerator of that query and send the model off to do work. After sending a record off so many times i attempt to make the necessary changes and save them. Like so:

```
foreach (var track in CurrentBatch)
        {
            if (track.MusicTrackFormatID == StartInfo.INPUTFORMATID1)
            {
                track.MusicTrackFormatID = StartInfo.OUTPUTFORMATID1;
                int strLeng= track.MusicTrackPath.Length;
                track.MusicTrackPath.Remove(strLeng - 2, 2);
                track.MusicTrackPath += StartInfo.OUTPUTFORMATID1.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                track.MusicTrackFormatID = StartInfo.OUTPUTFORMATID2;
                int strLeng = track.MusicTrackPath.Length;
                track.MusicTrackPath.Remove(strLeng - 2, 2);
                track.MusicTrackPath += StartInfo.OUTPUTFORMATID2.ToString();
            }
            _live.MusicTrackFiles.Find(track.MusicTrackFileID).MusicTrackFilename=track.MusicTrackFilename;
            _live.MusicTrackFiles.Find(track.MusicTrackFileID).MusicTrackFilename = track.MusicTrackPath;

        }
_live.SaveChanges();
```

EDIT BY REQUEST:
describing the above a little bit. _live is a Live datatype, which inherits DbContext. CurrentBatch is a list of MusicTrackFiles. MusicTrackFile is a model that represents a record in the MusicTrackFiles table.

The dataReader is made from using the Enumerator that is used like so:

```
if (CurrentBatch.Count >= BATCHSIZE)
        {
            saveBatch();
            CurrentBatch.Clear();
        }
            _queryEnumerator.MoveNext();
            CurrentBatch.Add(_queryEnumerator.Current);
            return _queryEnumerator.Current;
```

The above Enumerator is gotten from an IQueryable

The problem is that i get a Error stating that the connection is in use by the datareader and i need to close it. I've tried using MARS, I've tried using `_live.Database.BeginTransaction()` to make a new transaction. All of these wont work.

Any ideas on how to save mid read?

*Note I welcome code critique

Comment: What DataReader? What type is _live? What is CurrentBatch? http://sscce.org/

Comment: @reggaeguitar Ive edited my above post to answer your questions, and more.